# executeScript from RSelenium gives error with args

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I try to reproduce an example code from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html)

Here is the code:

```
library("RSelenium")
#start RSelenium server
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com/ncr")
script <- "return document.getElementById('hplogo').hidden;"
remDr$executeScript(script, args = list())
```

and for the last line I receive this error:

```
Selenium message:unknown error: 'args' must be a list
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I can't understand what happens with this error because `remDr$navigate` works and  `remDr$executeScript`. What is the difference with executeScript and gives this error?

Comment: try this `remDr$executeScript(script)`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried thank you but again the error is the same.

Comment: This may be a bug either in RSelenium as such. I assume few things that you are on latest version of RSelneium, Chrome and Chromedriver. Also try `remDr$executeScript(script, args = list("dummy"))`

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes this works for the code. Not sure what has changed because when I tested it worked and after some hour I opened the PC to work again it didn't work. Your last comment is the answer helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be a bug in RSelenium as such.

I assume few things that you are on latest version of RSelneium, Chrome and Chromedriver.

Use

`remDr$executeScript(script, args = list("dummy"))`